# How can I limit the number of dictionaries in NSUserDefaults stored on the basis of userID in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a dictionary having following details:

```
     {
            Name = "John";
            Picture =         (
                ""
            );
            Rating = 4;
        },
     {
            Name = "Peter";
            Picture =         (
                ""
            );
            Rating = 3;
        },
```

I am storing these `dictionaries` in `NSUserDefaults`. I want that a user having `userID` FED123RED123 can store only two such `dictionaries` in `NSUSerDefaults` and other user having different `userID` can store his two different values in `NSUSerDefaults`. In Short, how can I limit the number of `dictionaries` in `NSUserDefaults` stored on the basis of `userID`.

Comment: put them in array and limit the array to only have 2 values.

Comment: Don't store this sort of data in user defaults.

Comment: Like @Paulw11 said, NSUserDefaults is not intended to store anything beyond basic settings. Use a database instead, or atleast a flat file. That way, you have full control over how the data is organized and stored.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the structure something like this:

```
"FED123RED123" : [
                    {
                        Name = "John";
                        Picture =         (
                            ""
                        );
                        Rating = 4;
                    },
                    {
                        Name = "Peter";
                        Picture =         (
                            ""
                        );
                        Rating = 3;
                    }
            ]
```

And check if the count of array stored for particular user id is less than 2, then allow to add dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable of type `Dictionary`:

`var dictionary_to_save: [[String:AnyObject]]!`

Now, you may save the `userDefaults` to above dictionary and check the count of the same dictionary as above

```
var dictionary_to_save: [String:AnyObject]]?

func saving_to_defaults(){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let defaultsValue = defaults.objectForKey(object_name, forkey:"key_name")
        self.dictionary_to_save = defaultsValue
        if dictionary_to_save.count >= 2{
            // do nothing or, count is already two, so delete dictionaries added before as

            self.dictionary_to_save.removelast()

        }else{

        }
        //save object using userDefault here
        defaults.setObject(object_name, forKey: "key_name")
    }
```